# Turning a recurrence relation into a characteristic equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have the following recurrence to solve:

b<sub>n</sub> = 13b<sub>n-1</sub> - 22b<sub>n-2</sub> , n > 1           
Subject to b<sub>0</sub> = 3 , b<sub>1</sub> = 51

I've figured it out until b<sub>4</sub>:

b<sub>2</sub> = 597

b<sub>3</sub> = 6639

b<sub>4</sub> = 73173

Now I'm supposed to prove it. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: You can’t prove anything until you have something to prove, which in this case would be a closed form for $b_n$ as a function of $n$. Do you know what the characteristic equation is?

Comment: I wasn't sure if I actually had to do the characteristic equation or not; I assumed all I had to do was solve the recurrence. I'm not sure how to get it from the equation.

Comment: try $b_n = k^n$ and see what $k$ has to be.

Comment: Here’s a completely mechanical way. Replace each $b_k$ by $x^k$; you get $x^n=13x^{n-1}-22x^{n-2}$. Transpose everything to one side: $x^n-13x^{n-1}+22x^{n-2}=0$. Now factor out as big a power of $x$ as you can, and throw it away: $x^{n-2}(x^2-13x+22)=0$, then $x^2-13x+22=0$. That’s your characteristic equation. With a little practice you can write it down directly from the recurrence. The next step is to find its roots, which in this case can be done by factoring it.

Comment: Alright, I've got it factored out to (x-11)(x-2) = 0.

Comment: @Matt: So it has roots of $2$ and $11$. This means that every solution to the congruence, ignoring the initial conditions, has the form $b_n=A\cdot2^n+B\cdot11^n$. Substitute $n=0$ and $n=1$ into that, using the given values of $b_0$ and $b_1$, and you’ll have two linear equations in two unknowns, $A$ and $B$. Solve for $A$ and $B$, and you’ll have your closed form.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Sorry for delayed responses, I'm working out the problem. I'm a little confused. Does that mean it would be A(2^0) + B(11^0) and A(2^1) + B(11^1)?

Comment: @Matt: Yes, $b_0=A\cdot2^0+B\cdot11^0=A+B$; since $b_0=3$, your first equation is $A+B=3$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So the second equation would be 2A + 11B = 51?

Comment: @Matt: It would indeed.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott is it possible to put this into an identity matrix? It looks like it would be able to be put into that form.

Comment: @Matt: I’m not sure what you mean by that. You can use matrix methods to solve the system of equations, but it’s at least as easy just to use basic algebra. Subtracting twice the first from the second leaves you $9B=45$, from which you immediately get $B$, and then the first equation very easily gives you $A$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I remember my Professor saying that we could turn it into a matrix like this:

[1   2  3 |1 0 0]
[2 11 51|0 1 0]

Sorry if this is terribly formatted, it's hard to format stuff in the comments.

Comment: @Matt: I don’t at the moment see what he had in mind. If you made it $$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&3\\2&11&51\end{bmatrix}\;,$$ it would be the augmented matrix of the system, but as I say, that technique strikes me as overkill here.

Comment: Yeah, he enjoys matrices a lot. What would be an easier way to do this, then?

Comment: No not easier, but more insightful.  One way to solve this is to observe: $$\begin{bmatrix} b_{n+1} \\ b_{n} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 13 & -22   \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} b_{n} \\ b_{n-1} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 13 & -22   \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^n \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_0 \end{bmatrix}$$  while it does explain *why* characteristic equations work (think eigenvalue), it isn't necessarily easier.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Going back to your original answer of how to solve it algebraically, I don't really see where you got it from.